# Reading binary file to a 2D array in C

Tags: c, file, binary

I have no idea how to do this. Here is the simplified version of my code. I am supposed to read off a binary file to a 2D array.

```
void readf(const char *fname, int a[50][50]){
    int i=0;
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen(fname,"rb");
    fread(a[i], sizeof(int), 1, f);
}
```

I tried using for loops and &a and `a[i][j]` and I ended up with this.

The file I am trying to read is .bin file and it only contains 0s and 1s

Comment: You should be able to read the whole array in one go with `fread`, but of course this entirely depends on the file format, which we know nothing about.

Comment: file format please ?

Comment: If you are doing it in C, the question should not be tagged `c++`.

Comment: By file format you mean .bin?

Comment: Does the file contain only the integers you are interested in, and are they stored in the same size/number of bytes than `int` on your system?

Comment: What kind of loops have you tried, and in which way did the code not do what you expected?

Comment: The file should contain only 0s and 1s. And everytime I try to print this array it's all 0s

Comment: No, by file format I mean how are you actually storing data in this file? Because you should store it the same way as you read it.

Comment: I actually downloaded the file. It is supposed to have same information as the text file that I downloaded. I figured out how to read a text file, now I need to figure out how to read a binary file